# Do anti-pregnancy pills have a negative effect on health?

Tags: medical-science, medications

Is it true that women who 'go on the pill' experience effects like vomiting, head-aches, skin-problems more than women who don't? Are these pills actually bad for health?

Comment: Related: [Does taking a contraceptive pill increase your chance of getting cancer?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3082)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does taking a contraceptive pill increase your chance of getting cancer?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3082/does-taking-a-contraceptive-pill-increase-your-chance-of-getting-cancer)

Comment: Not a duplicate; this is a much broader question.

Comment: how is this not answerable by just reading the listed side effects which come with the medication?

Comment: The overall answer can only be arrived at by weighing the costs and the benefits personally. Pregnancy is not risk-free or consequence free. The side effects, and their relative cost versus the cost of pregnancy, can only be judged by the individual. But they need to be well informed, which is why this a good question.

Comment: Does "anti-pregnancy" mean contraceptive or abortifacient?

Comment: Of course, pregnancy also has side effects.

Comment: Of course the birth control pill can have side effects.  Contraceptive failure also has risks, though--and for a young, nonsmoker these dominate.  For such women the pill is safer than any barrier contraception even if you figure she will promptly abort an oops.  (Carrying to term increases the risk 10x, I haven't seen anything on comparing this to the pill risk.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I copy below the side effects reported on MedlinePlus (part of the National Library of Medicine, NIH).

Every drug may have side effects. Those will vary with every person and the dosage used. If you read the prospect that comes with the drug, you can find all the reported side effects in there. It will include the side effects observed during the clinical trials as well as any post market effect observed during phase IV studies. **Does this mean that every person will have problems? No. Will these problems be serious? It depends.** All it means is that these effects have been observed, and the most probable cause is the drug administration. As always, ask your doctor!

http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/druginfo/meds/a601050.html#side-effects

> What side effects can this medication
>   cause? Oral
>   contraceptives may cause side effects.
>   Tell your doctor if any of these
>   symptoms are severe or do not go away:
>
> nausea
>
> vomiting
>
> stomach cramps or bloating
>
> diarrhea
>
> constipation
>
> gingivitis (swelling of the gum tissue)
>
> increased or decreased appetite
>
> weight gain or weight loss
>
> brown or black skin patches
>
> acne
>
> hair growth in unusual places
>
> bleeding or spotting between menstrual periods
>
> changes in menstrual flow
>
> painful or missed periods
>
> breast tenderness, enlargement, or discharge
>
> swelling, redness, irritation, burning, or itching of the vagina
>
> white vaginal discharge
>
> Some side effects can be serious. The
>   following symptoms are uncommon, but
>   if you experience any of them, call
>   your doctor immediately:
>
> severe headache
>
> severe vomiting
>
> speech problems
>
> dizziness or faintness
>
> weakness or numbness of an arm or leg
>
> crushing chest pain or chest heaviness
>
> coughing up blood
>
> shortness of breath
>
> pain, warmth, or heaviness in the back of the lower leg
>
> partial or complete loss of vision
>
> double vision
>
> bulging eyes
>
> severe stomach pain
>
> yellowing of the skin or eyes
>
> loss of appetite
>
> extreme tiredness, weakness, or lack of energy
>
> fever
>
> dark-colored urine
>
> light-colored stool
>
> swelling of the hands, feet, ankles or lower legs
>
> depression, especially if you also have trouble sleeping, tiredness, loss
>   of energy, or other mood changes
>
> unusual bleeding
>
> rash
>
> menstrual bleeding that is unusually heavy or that lasts for
>   longer than 7 days in a row
>
> Oral contraceptives may increase the
>   chance that you will develop liver
>   tumors. These tumors are not a form of
>   cancer, but they can break and cause
>   serious bleeding inside the body. Oral
>   contraceptives may also increase the
>   chance that you will develop breast or
>   liver cancer, or have a heart attack,
>   a stroke, or a serious blood clot.
>   Talk to your doctor about the risks of
>   using oral contraceptives.
>
> Oral contraceptives may cause other
>   side effects. Call your doctor if you
>   have any unusual problems while taking
>   this medication.
>
> If you experience a serious side
>   effect, you or your doctor may send a
>   report to the Food and Drug
>   Administration's (FDA) MedWatch
>   Adverse Event Reporting program online
>   [at
>   http://www.fda.gov/Safety/MedWatch] or
>   by phone [1-800-332-1088].

Comment: This answer could probably be more relevant, if it had some ballpark figures for how many women experience side effects (percentage wise).